# Need help for android multiplayer game development

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am new on gaming in android.
I have to start my new project which is nothing but a mutiplayer game
I want to know that whether android supports multiplayer gaming??
If yes, is there any **sdk/game engine/library** or anything else which will 
support for multiplayer gaming.
I read about it in many blogs but I didn't found any useful information.
`openfeint, plus+, scoreloop , crystal` are do not provide support for android multiplayer game.

If you know anything regarding this please share it 
any **blog/documentation/sample app/ demo** will help me a lot.

Thanks,
Mahaveer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andengine is great, but in terms of Multiplayer game-play, it offers only close proximity multiplayer (BlueTooth or same network WIFI connection).

If you want to your users to play with each other on a global scale i would recommend [Skiller SDK](http://www.skiller-games.com)

Hope i helped..

Comment: Thanks MrWhiteYoo... for the suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android does support multiplayer gaming.

I suggest you go through basic Android tutorials before you start with game development.

Read about this [Game](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-game-idea.html) and the way it is developed.

Also, this [blog](http://organicandroid.blogspot.com/2010/11/creating-2d-games-with-android-and.html) will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

AndEngine has an extension for multiplayer, check it out.

Comment: It got no any documentation on Extension